# How do I persistently take input from the console in Python

Tags: python, function, arguments

I'm trying to make a to-do list terminal app in Python, and I want to be able to persistently pass and take arguments such as "task add" or "sort date." How can I do this? The `input` function only goes once and I don't want to make a loop if I can avoid it.

Comment: _I don't want to make a loop_ Why not?  If you want to repeat something over and over, loops are the natural mechanism for doing that.

Comment: You are going to have to make a loop in order to continually get input from the user. Otherwise, you'd need to write out the same input statement hundreds of times and then the program would suddenly stop after the hundredth time.

Comment: @Column01 I *think* I figured it out by reading john gordon's comment - would it be correct to create a While/True loop that continually listens for input, and execute certain functions if that input is equal to a certain value? Many thanks.

Comment: What I would do is define a function called `ask` or something and have it wait for input, and then parse it for different commands and execute other functions for said commands. Finally return and have ask call itself again so it starts the ask process again.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this continue input script is what you need for your task.

```
print('Continue Input for John Allison')

while True:
    task_add = float(int(input('Task Add: ')))
    print(task_add)
```

Comment: Why `float(int(...))` and not just `float(...)`? Why `float` or `int` at all? What if the inputs are supposed to be to-do items as text?

Comment: @mkrieger1 What if they are floats?  You should just post a answer to the limited information.